# How can i access to a property of class before its value sets first time

Tags: c#

i know the "IFirePropertyChanged" interface.

But i dont know something like "IFirePropertyBeforeChange".

is there exists?

Comment: Why can't you set it in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[INotifyPropertyChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging.aspx).  Note this was introduced only in .NET 3.5, and may not be widely supported by frameworks.

Comment: do u know that it has a "post sharp" implementation?

Comment: i am using .Net 3.5.no problem for me.

Comment: Ah, sorry, don't know about PostSharp support for it.  But if you've got a PostSharp thing for INotifyPropertyChanged then it should be an easy change to adapt it for INotifyPropertyChanging.